# How to use variable in MAUI AndroidManifest.xml file based on configuration

Tags: variables, configuration, android-manifest, maui, parametrize

I'd like to use different values for dev,qa,prod environments in .Net MAUI app AndroidManifest.xml file or different version of the file like AndroidManifest.dev.xml, AndroidManifest.release.xml.

I could not find any example, can someone point me right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files provide an easy and efficient way to manage environment based settings and variables.
You can start by following steps:

**1.creating Build Configurations in your project**

[image]

**2.Configure Android Manifest Files for your Environments**

You can start by creating `AndroidManifest` for all your environments. You can duplicate the existing `AndroidManifest.xml` and rename it for each environment in your solution.

And then edit your `.csproj` file:

```
<AndroidManifest>Platforms\Android\$(Configuration)\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

3.Set up Environment Based Configuration.

4.Read Configurations

Note:

The specific method of setting and reading variables is different, but the overall implementation process is similar.

For more information, you can refer to the following links:

[How to switch AndroidManifest.xml for multiple Android builds.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13155)

[Managing Configurations](https://ahmadharis.github.io/2020-05-14-Xamarin-Android-Configurations/).